# Swift MacOS Change Array value for whole app

Tags: arrays, swift, macos

I am new to swift but was wondering if someone could advise what I am doing wrong with the code below.

What i am intending to do is to make the original array declared above the class, change to 4 3 2 1 once the change array button is clicked. This works and the console outputs 4321 as expected if i click the button. However, once i click the print array button it shows the original array i first declared 1-2-3-4. How do I overwrite the original array with the new one i made on the change array button?

- So intended behaviour press print array see 1 2 3 4
- Press change array button
- Now print array should show 4 3 2 1 and not 1 2 3 4 which it does.

Thanks

```
import Cocoa

let shuffledNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3]; // declare array

class ViewController: NSViewController {
// change array button
    @IBAction func arraychange(_ sender: Any) {
          let shuffledNumbers = [4, 3, 2, 1];
        print(shuffledNumbers);
      }

    // print array to console
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        print(shuffledNumbers);
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared your variable at the global level but you're also declaring it within the `func arraychange(_ sender)` function by using `let` again. In other words, you're creating a new variable also called `shuffledNumbers` that goes away as soon as the function ends.

You probably want to do the following:

1. Not declare `shuffleNumbers` as a global variable. Declare it inside your class
2. In the `arracychange(_ sender:)` function, *update* the `shuffleNumbers` array by removing the `let`.

You definitely want to remove the semi colons at the end of your lines. They may be valid, but they're not Swifty.

Comment: thanks so much i just noticed that issue myself appreciate your help sir !

Comment: You're welcome. I've done the same thing myself. Feel free to mark my answer as correct :-)